# Style WPF-ContextMenu with dynamic MenuItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a styled ContextMenu.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ComboBoxContextMenu" Style="{StaticResource style_ContextMenu}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource style_MenutItem}" Header="{Binding ExtraMenuItem1}" Visibility="{Binding ExtraMenuItem1Visibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" Command="{Binding ExtraMenuItemCommand}" CommandParameter="MenuItem1_Click" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
</ContextMenu>
```

Everything looks fine. If I replace the MenuItems with the ViewModel-First approach everything works fine while the style is broken.
How can I rescue the design? Do I get something like a ListBox when I a add the MenuItems in code?

DynContextMenuBehavior.cs

```
public class DynContextMenuBehavior
{
 ...
    private void OnMenuOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContextMenu.ItemsSource = ContextMenuHandler.GetMenuItems();
    }
}
```

DataTemplateResourceDictionary.xaml

```
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MenuItemViewModel}">
    <views:MenuItemView />
</DataTemplate>
...
```

MenuItemView.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="ContextMenus.View.MenuItemView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextMenus.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <MenuItem
        Style="{StaticResource style_MenutItem}"
        Header="{Binding Header}"
        Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
</UserControl>
```

MenuItemViewModel.cs

```
public class MenuItem : IMenuItem
{
...
}
```

**Edit**

Styles

```
<Style x:Key="style_MenutItem" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">

</Style>

<Style x:Key="style_ContextMenu" TargetType="ContextMenu">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                <Border Name="Border" Margin="5" MinWidth="100" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: ContextMenu has a StackPanel set to IsItemsHost=True by default. You could put whatever in there you need though. I don't however see any of your style/control templates so I'm not sure what you mean by rescue the design?

Comment: I have added the styles. "rescue" means both ContextMenus should look the same.